# Cocos2d-iphone v2 - adinterstitialads show in portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, iad, cocos2d-iphone-2.x

I have implemented the adinterstitialad into my game (cocos2d-iphone v2).
I have my game set only in landscape mode. When the ad loads it does from left to right and the orientation is the portrait one.
What can I do to force in landscape only?

Comment: not having any issues with that ... show your code.

Comment: well now i locked the device to show only the landscape. The ad shows from left to right (it should be from bottom to top) then it rotate. I'd need it only from bottom to top without rotation.
Another thing is the rotation of ad. While the display rotation is locked only for 2 landscape orientations, the adinterstitial responds on all the 4 orientations.